# Rowwise while loop over dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, while-loop, dplyr

I have a function calculating something based on input variables, but I want to change the input variables depending on the result of the function. I feel that it is a very trivial question, but I have not found a working solution yet.

I have a dataset similar to this:

```r
v1<-sample(5:12, 10, replace=T)
v2<-rep(100, 10)
v3<-rep(1,10)
v4<-sample(1:4, 10, replace=T)
t1<-sample(10:30, 10, replace=T)
```

And a function which uses the variables v1 to v4 to calculate something:

```r
fun<-function(v1, v2, v3, v4){
  #does complicated things
  result<-((v2/(v1*v4))*v3
  return(result)
}

out<-fun(v1, v2, v3, v4)
df<-data.frame(v1, v2, v3, v4, t1, out)
```

I need t1 < out. For non-vectorized data this seems to work:

```r
while (out < t1){
  v3= v3 + 1
  out<- fun(v1, v2, v3, v4)
}
```

Ideally the last value for v3 is stored somehow.

```r
v1  v1  v2 v3 v4 t1 out out_new v3_new
1   6 100  1  2 15  8.333333 16 2
2  12 100  1  2 17  4.166667 20 5
3   5 100  1  1 12 20.000000 20 1
4  10 100  1  4 26  2.500000 . . 
5   8 100  1  2 15  6.250000 . .
6   6 100  1  3 18  5.555556 
7  10 100  1  4 20  2.500000 
8  11 100  1  2 12  4.545455 
9  12 100  1  3 28  2.777778
10  6 100  1  2 25  8.333333
```

The output I am looking for is a dataframe looking like this:
What I am looking for is a vectorized solution that works on a large (100.000 rows) dataframe/tibble. I have tried different approaches with dplyr (mutate with case_when, ifelse) but have failed to come up with a working solution.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you show your expected final output?

Comment: What exactly is it you want to calculate in the end? Why not just claculate the entire result for all rows and then use `filter` to remove rows where `t1 >= out`. `df %>% mutate(out = fun(v1, v2, v3, v4)) %>% filter(t1 < out)`.

Comment: If you dont want to filter away rows you could change `filter` to a second `mutate(out = ifelse(t1 >= out, NULL, out))`

Comment: I think he wants to increase `v3` till `out` is bigger than t1.

Comment: That makes sense. The question is whether `v3` should be updated in the result, and whether it is fixed intervals it is increased by. Using `v3 + seq(n())` in mutate would accomplish the effect of the `while` loop as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to achieve this using `dplyr::rowwise()`:

```
library(tidyverse)
v1<-sample(5:12, 10, replace=T)
v2<-rep(100, 10)
v3<-rep(1,10)
v4<-sample(1:4, 10, replace=T)
t1<-sample(10:30, 10, replace=T)

fun<-function(v1, v2, v3, v4){
  #does complicated things
  result<-(v1/v2)*v4*v3
  return(result)
}

reallyWeirdFunction = function(v1, v2, v3, v4, t){
  out<- fun(v1, v2, v3, v4)
  while (out < t){
    v3= v3 + 1
    out<- fun(v1, v2, v3, v4)
  }
  out
}

df<-data.frame(v1, v2, v3, v4, t1)
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(
    out=fun(v1, v2, v3, v4), 
    out2=reallyWeirdFunction(v1, v2, v3, v4, t1)
  )
#> # A tibble: 10 x 7
#> # Rowwise: 
#>       v1    v2    v3    v4    t1   out  out2
#>    <int> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1     7   100     1     3    17  0.21  17.0
#>  2    11   100     1     2    24  0.22  24.2
#>  3    12   100     1     1    11  0.12  11.0
#>  4    10   100     1     4    15  0.4   15.2
#>  5    10   100     1     2    22  0.2   22  
#>  6     9   100     1     1    16  0.09  16.0
#>  7     5   100     1     2    24  0.1   24  
#>  8    12   100     1     2    23  0.24  23.0
#>  9     8   100     1     3    30  0.24  30  
#> 10     7   100     1     2    14  0.14  14.

Created on 2020-08-28 by the reprex package (v0.3.0)
```

However, this is usually a very bad idea to use while loops in R, and `rowwise()` can be very slow in large datasets. You should definitely try to find a better algorithm than incrementing v3 like you are doing. I could not find one for your example though.

Comment: This is what I was looking for! I think jogo's approach may be faster with large datasets though. Thank you!

Comment: @user45017 Beware, Jogo's approach does not yearn the exact same results. I'm not sure why and which one is correct though, this might come from the strictness of the comparison.

Comment: I ran a little benchmark on a 100k rows sample and both approached have same exact speed :-)

Answer (score 0):

With `mapply()` and some other definitions you can do in base R:

```
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(v1=sample(5:12, 10, replace=T), v2=rep(100, 10), v3=rep(1,10), 
                 v4=sample(1:4, 10, replace=T), t1=sample(10:30, 10, replace=T))

fun<-function(v1, v2, v3, v4) {
  #does complicated things
  result <- ((v2/(v1*v4))*v3)
  return(result)
}

fun2 <- function(v1, v2, v3, v4, t) {
  out <- fun(v1, v2, v3, v4)
  while (out < t){
    v3 <- v3 + 1
    out <- fun(v1, v2, v3, v4)
  }
  return(list(v3new=v3, out=out))
}

cbind(df, t(mapply(fun2, df$v1, df$v2, df$v3, df$v4, df$t1)))
> cbind(df, t(mapply(fun2, df$v1, df$v2, df$v3, df$v4, df$t1)))
#    v1  v2 v3 v4 t1 v3new      out
# 1   5 100  1  3 24     4 26.66667
# 2   9 100  1  4 12     5 13.88889
# 3   5 100  1  3 18     3       20
# 4   5 100  1  4 13     3       15
# 5   6 100  1  1 14     1 16.66667
# 6   8 100  1  1 22     2       25
# 7   6 100  1  2 14     2 16.66667
# 8   6 100  1  4 29     7 29.16667
# 9   5 100  1  2 11     2       20
# 10 12 100  1  2 17     5 20.83333
```

Comment: I wonder why your method is rounding `out`, it seems really similar to mine though.

Comment: I see now that my mistake was that when I tried to make the second function work forgot to define "out" before the while loop. Thanks for the solution!

Comment: @DanChaltiel I can not replicate your data, because you are not using `set.seed(...)` in your code.

Comment: @Jogo true, but in fact it was because of a mistake in your code: you are using `df$v2` twice ;-)